# What do I need to read before understanding "Kierkegaard: Attack upon Christendom"?

Tags: kierkegaard

So far I have read "Either/or", "Repetition", Plato's dialogues, "Nicomachean Ethics", "Meditations" by Marcus Aurelius and I'm quite familiar with Christianity. Which other primary texts or some kind of secondary source do I need to be familiar with in order to understand this text?

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have begun a commitment to reading Kierkegaard and need some guidance in understanding of him, I was not a Philosophy student in university.

Answer (score 1):

Me again. For this one, I don't think you need to read anything! You could do that whole process I described for reading the Sickness, then read the Sickness, and I think you'll be in the best possible *position* to read the Attack, but I don't think you need any secondary literature to help you read this one. I would however suggest at least a bit of familiarization with Kierkegaard's concepts, terms, and life story. These can be found on Youtube; I think the best one is by Eric Dodson.

[Kierkegaard in 19 Minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RtlwWMJILBA) (Youtube video essay).

Good luck!